# What doctypes are available in Yesod Hamlet?

Tags: doctype, yesod, hamlet

In Hamlet, `$doctype 5` generates `<!DOCTYPE html>`.  [The Yesod book says](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/shakespearean-templates) that "We have support for a number of different versions of a `doctype`", but does not document these.  What other doctypes are supported and what is the syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see the list in the source code:

https://github.com/yesodweb/shakespeare/blob/master/hamlet/Text/Hamlet/Parse.hs#L526

The theory behind this was that people were going to ask for all the additional doctypes that they needed, and once we had a comprehensive list, we'd put it in the docs. It seems that no one cared about anything but the HTML 5 doctype.